# What's the best way to export an HTML table to CSV if it has some cells with text and other cells with just a value attribute?

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

Essentially I'm trying to export a table with the following structure to CSV:

[image]

As you can see, there's a mix of text values and input values, which is making it difficult to get the whole table without any blank values. I found some code that mostly works, but results in cells with just "$" or "%" when the cell is an input:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),


        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row), $cols = $row.find('td,th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col), text = $col.text();
                console.log($col.text())
                console.log($col)
                // console.log($col)
                // console.log(j)

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',



        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        console.log(csv);

        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
            //alert('IE' + csv);
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"}), "csvname.csv")
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': csvData, 'target': '_blank' });
        }
}
```

Does anybody have a suggestion on what approach I might take to get the node value and substitute it in where the cell lacks a text value? I tried getting .innerText, but for some reason that seemed to break the functionality of the table (updating inputs would no longer update the output). Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: `text = $('input', $col).length > 0 : $('input', $col).val() + $col.text() : $col.text()`

Answer (score 0):

Wild beard solved it, albeit with a typo in the ternary operator syntax. Here's the corrected version:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),


        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row), $cols = $row.find('td,th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col)

                text = $('input', $col).length > 0 ? $('input', $col).val() 
                + $col.text() : $col.text()

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',



        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        console.log(csv);

        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
            //alert('IE' + csv);
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"}), "csvname.csv")
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr({ 'download': filename, 'href': csvData, 'target': '_blank' });
        }
}
```